# Interest in turning on the YouTube viewer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In Astronomy SE meta I asked [Interest in looking into adding the YouTube viewer?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/482/7982) and the justification was straightforward; in my answer there I documented almost 40 previous posts with links to videos in YouTube and several of my own posts I felt could take advantage of it.

Once the case was made it appeared that the process of getting the embedded YouTube viewer in Astronomy SE appeared to be straightforward, though I don't know what all went on behind the scenes.

To test if it was already turned on, I added a link to a relevant and potentially helpful YouTube video https://youtu.be/eIHQHlbxtmk to [Okay, I've installed LAMMPS II: I'd like to make a small graphene flake, but how?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9068/201) and so far the viewer does not display. See also:

- https://lammpstube.com/videos/
- https://lammpstube.com/instructional-videos/

I've done a quick search here and found [15 instances of "youtube"](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/search?q=youtube) and [3 of "youtu.be"](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22youtu.be%22)

**Question:** How much interest is there here in Matter Modeling SE in turning on the YouTube viewer?

[image: I can has (cheezeburger) YouTube?]

Comment: I think it's a good idea!

Answer (score 3):

For me personally, I can't see needing embedded youtube clips. For short clips where its just introducing a short animation, I would just include a gif. For longer clips or sections of a video, I would usually rather just jump to youtube than watch in an embedded player. The example you gave was a 4 minute tutorial, which if I came across I would probably just watch on youtube or save to a watch later playlist. I'm open to asking SE to enable this if there is enough interest, but I personally don't see the need.

Comment: Certainly it isn't needed, but what are the downsides to enabling it? It seems to me it would just be a small quality of life improvement for those who might use it.

Comment: @HaydenS Assuming there aren't any performance issues (e.g. pages load a lot slower due to this being enabled), I don't see any problem with asking the CMs. I'd just rather wait to see if enough people are interested, since the CMs are fairly busy and I don't want to add something unnecessarily (especially if we wind up having another request that gets put further back in line because we already asked for this to be enabled).